# Re-size electron app window dynamically

Tags: javascript, electron, atom-editor

### Main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let win;  
app.on('ready', createWindow);
function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow();
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'main.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
    // Open the DevTools.
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    });
}
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

### main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyApp</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello !</h1>
<button id="resizeBtn">Resize</button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I want that if user click on button ,then a function should trig and change the size of main window which is already opened.i know that `win.setSize(width,height)` can do this but i don't know how to put this in a function.i don't know how to get reference of Button in main.js to add an event listener on that or how to get the current window and apply some operations.i am new to electron !
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer (from mobile): use ipcRender module to send event to main and call the resize method.

**Long answer:**
I cannot find a playground for electron!

```
// In renderer process (web page).
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
const myResizeBtn = document.getElementById('resizeBtn')
myResizeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  ipcRenderer.send('resize-me-please')
})

// in main.js

const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('resize-me-please', (event, arg) => {
  win.setSize(width,height)
})
```

Comment: `const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
ipcRenderer.onData('resize', function (e, x, y) {
    win.setSize(x, y);
});     const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
    let btn = document.querySelector('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ipcRenderer.send('resize', 600, 800);
    });`

Comment: Take a look to this [page](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/)

Comment: thanks ! i already found the mistake i did in my code ! i was using ipcRenderer instead of using ipcMain in main.js ! but thanks i accepted your answer !

Comment: where do you define "win"?

Comment: In the `main.js` line 5

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can get the current BrowserWindow in code, and resize it like the following:

```js
const {remote} = require('electron');

const win = remote.getCurrentWindow();

let height = 400;
let width = 200; 
let animate = false;

win.setSize(width, height, animate);
```

About BrowserWindow.setSize(), it got three params.

1. width Integer
2. height Integer
3. animate Boolean (optional) macOS

You can find more about the BrowserWindow setSize method in the official doc https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window.

Comment: `remote` is already deprecated, so this is probably not the approach people should use.

Comment: It just is in different package now: "@electron/remote". So I would argue it is still a usefull approach.

Comment: remote is its own module now because it is bad to use it. read the module description. It warns to use it. there is a electron blog post about why they did that somewhere going into details why using remote is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

use this,
this works

```
    function createWindow() {
      // Create the browser window.
      const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ useContentSize: true });
      const view = new BrowserView();
      mainWindow.setBrowserView(view);
      view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 });
      view.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });
      view.webContents.loadURL("https://youtube.com");
    }
```

Comment: The OP asked how to resize the window based on the content, the solution you provide is "how to fit the content when the user resize the window". totally different matter

Answer (score 0):

It works like charm in JS, typescript

```
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">
    <body>
        <script>
            function resize() {
                var ipc = window.require("electron").ipcRenderer;
                ipc.send("resize-window", 400, 200);
            }
        </script>
        <div>
          <button onclick="resize()">Reload again</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not work in vanilla Electron.js, you have to implement `"resize-window"` IPC in the main process, see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46566908/254109 (Try in Electron Fiddle).

Comment: your code does not make use of TypeScript in the example